# Reference on the question mark cell complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

The question mark complex is a finite spectrum whose cohomology looks like a "question mark" (when drawn as a module over the Steenrod algebra): that is, there is an element in dimension zero $a_0$, an element $a_2 = \mathrm{Sq}^2 a_0$, and an element $a_6 = \mathrm{Sq}^4 a_2$. It can be constructed by starting with $\Sigma^{-2} \mathbb{CP}^2$, which maps to $S^2$ (thanks to the cofiber sequence $S^1 \to S^0 \to \Sigma^{-2} \mathbb{CP}^2 \to S^2$) and lifting the map $\nu: S^5 \to S^2$ to $\Sigma^{-2} \mathbb{CP}^2$ (which can be done since $\eta \nu = 0$). Then, one takes the cofiber of $S^5 \to \Sigma^{-2}\mathbb{CP}^2$.

Does anyone know any good references on this? I'd like, ideally, to see a few example computations done with it; as it is I don't really have much intuition for how to work with it.

Comment: have you tried constructing a similar complex but with $sq^1$ and $sq^2$ instead?

Comment: Hi Sean. There is such a complex (same logic as above, using $2 \eta = 0$ instead of $\eta \nu = 0$). I'd be interested in seeing computations, e.g., of the stable homotopy of this complex as well. 

Comment: Well you can at least get information about its k-theory pretty easily. Have you tried that? (given the level of questions you ask I am sure this is all the suggestion you need)

Comment: I don't know what the $K$-theory operations look like, actually. The AHSS degenerates and $K^0(?)$ is free on three generators; there's a cofiber sequence $S^0 \to ? \to \Sigma^{-2} \mathbb{HP}^2$ which means that we know the $K$-theory operations except for one: the generator lifting the element of $K^0(S^0)$ could have strange Adams operations --- kind of like what happens in "On the groups J(X) IV." 

Comment: I was thinking you would use an Adams SS to compute its connective real k-theory...

Comment: There are a couple more references, also related to the Picard group - the dual of the question mark complex is referenced in Goerss-Henn-Mahowald-Rezk's "Picard groups at chromatic level 2 for $p = 3$" paper - they at least tell you a bit about its $K$ theory and $KO$ theory. There are also some (hard!) calculations in Ichigi-Shimomura's "$E(2)_*$-invertible spectra smashing with the Smith-Toda spectrum $V(1)$ at the prime 3" (see section 3 in particular)

Comment: Thanks! It's strange how the complex keeps coming up in Picard group papers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is hardly a "canonical example", but one place I've seen the question mark complex $Q$ in action is in Hovey and Sadofsky's paper *Invertible spectra in the $E(n)$-local stable homotopy category*.  There they compute that the even part of the Picard group of the $E(1)$-local stable category at $p = 2$ is generated by (the $E(1)$-localization of) $Q$.  As a warning, the exposition at the tail of the paper where this appears is a bit skeletal; you'll be working out the details of the computations and digging up references on your own.

But, in turn, they do cite Hopkins' *Minimal atlases of real projective spaces* for some facts about $Q$, which I have not read but looks to be useful.  He seems to call the complex $N_2$ in section 7, for reasons he explains pertaining to the cohomology of $bo\langle i \rangle$.

Comment: For whatever reason, googling "question mark cell complex" did not turn up anything. 

Comment: Sure thing. It's a bit of a silly name, certainly easier for humans to remember than for Google.